# UIImagePickerController picking bad quality images from Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I’m using normal tap gesture on ‘UIImageView’ when presenting an UIImagePickerController. But I don’t know why the images picked from Photo Library are always coming out to be bad quality(blurred, cropped etc.). When picking from Camera the images come out to be perfectly fine.

[image: IMAGE FROM PHOTO LIBRARY]

[image: IMAGE FROM CAMERA]

Here is complete code for this custom view class.

```
class ImageEditingView: UIView {

let imageView = UIImageView()

weak var delegate: ViewController!

var croppingRect: CGRect?
var croppedRect: CGRect?

var ratioWidth: CGFloat? {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
var ratioHeight: CGFloat? {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    // Drawing code

    let padding: CGFloat = 20

    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(center: rect.midPoint, size: rect.size - padding)
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePickerConroller)))
    self.addSubview(imageView)



    if let imageWidth = ratioWidth, let imageHeight = ratioHeight {
        if imageWidth > imageHeight {
            let newImageHeight = imageHeight/imageWidth * (rect.size.width - (2 * padding))
            let yForCroppedRect = (self.bounds.size.height - newImageHeight)/2
            self.croppingRect = CGRect(x: padding, y: yForCroppedRect, width: rect.size.width - (2 * padding), height: newImageHeight)
        } else if imageWidth < imageHeight {
            let newImageWidth = imageWidth/imageHeight * (rect.size.height - (2 * padding))
            let xForCroppedRect = (self.bounds.size.width - newImageWidth)/2
            self.croppingRect = CGRect(x: xForCroppedRect, y: padding, width: newImageWidth, height: rect.size.height - (2 * padding))
        } else {
            self.croppingRect = nil
        }
    }

    let bigRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
    let smallRect = self.croppingRect ?? self.imageView.frame
    self.croppedRect = smallRect
    let pathBigRect = UIBezierPath(rect: bigRect)
    let pathSmallRect = UIBezierPath(rect: smallRect)

    pathBigRect.append(pathSmallRect)
    pathBigRect.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fillLayer.path = pathBigRect.cgPath
    fillLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    //fillLayer.opacity = 0.4
    self.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
}

@objc func openImagePickerConroller() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary//.camera
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.delegate.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}

extension ImageEditingView: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.image = pickedImage
        self.ratioWidth = 10
        self.ratioHeight = 10
        self.delegate.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.delegate.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}

extension CGRect {
init(center: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
    let origin = CGPoint(x: center.x - (size.width/2), y: center.y - (size.height/2))
    self.init(origin: origin, size: size)
}

var midPoint: CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: self.midX, y: self.midY)
}
}

extension CGSize {
static func -(size: CGSize, diff: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    let dim = size.width <= size.height ? size.width : size.height
    return CGSize(width: dim - diff, height: dim - diff)
}
}
```

Comment: Are the images you are selecting from photo gallery of high res?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Yes they are high res images

Comment: What is the ratio used for? `ratioWidth` and `ratioHeight`. Also what happens if you comment it out?

Comment: It doesn't help if I comment those out. I drawing a darkGray layer around the UIImage as you can see in the above images. It doesn't really affect. But if you are still wondering I have shared complete code above.

Comment: change the line of code  self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill  with self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit  it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing on iOS 13.0 beta by any chance? Try it again with the latest iOS 13 beta, which should fix this bug.